# How to use integer in statement

Tags: java, mysql

I want to use the input of textfield "inputAge" to find the user with that age in mysql, how should I use the "int godine" in the Query.

```
Statement st = conn.createStatement();
int godine = Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText());
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from person where age = godine");

while (rs.next()) {
   korisnik = new Korisnik(rs.getInt("id"), rs.getString("name"), rs.getInt("age"), rs.getString("adress"), rs.getInt("income"));
   korisnik_lista.add(korisnik);
}
```

Comment: You'll use a `PreparedStatement` rather than a `Statement`.

Comment: I tried but I still don't know how exactly to use it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use prepared  statement and binding param

```
int godine = Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText());
String sqlStmt = "select * from person where age =  ?";
prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(sqlStmt);
prepStmt.setInt(1, godine);
ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
rs.close(); 
prepStmt.close();
```

Comment: @JoopEggen  thanks  ..  answer updated ..  up .. somewhere

Answer (score 0):

You could use prepared statement -it's recommended- as user [scaisEdge](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3522312/scaisedge) answered.

Also you could write the code as follows:

```
int godine = Integer.parseInt(inputAge.getText());
String sqlStmt = "select * from person where age = " + godine;
```

...

then execute with that statement will result right but not dynamic of course.